# WordPress: Check if plugin is installed (ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to prevent `fatal error` in my theme if the ACF plugin is deactivated or not installed.

The main function of the plugin is `get_field()`.
I wrote this code in my `functions.php` to check:

```
if ( !function_exists('get_field') ) {
  function get_field() {
    echo '<span>plugin ACF is not installed</span>';
  }
}
```

Please tell me this is acceptable practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this is not the main plugin function, just one of them. Probably, most commonly used by a plugin user in a theme. Another one is `the_field()`, which actually prints value (`get_field()` returns it).

Regarding practice of defining your custom function - it's fine. However, I would not print that long message in every place where ACF field is expected - some of them may be short (numbers), and this message will break the layout. Printing something shorter is better, imo.

Also, `function_exists` is proper check, not `is_plugin_active`, because ACF can also be shipped as a library with a theme framework or other plugin.

Another option is to remove ACF dependency on the frontend completely. You can output the contents of the fields with `get_post_meta()` and prevent ACF plugin from loading on the frontend entirely. See these two posts for details:

http://www.billerickson.net/code/disable-acf-frontend/

http://www.billerickson.net/advanced-custom-fields-frontend-dependency/

Comment: It's really cool! I would never have thought of this on their own. Now I will write the code a little bit better quality. Thank You for your experience!

Answer (score 29):

ACF itself uses a check to see if the framework has been loaded. If it has already been included and invoked by another plugin or theme, then ACF won't re-instantiate its own class again. It does this with a class check:

```
if (!class_exists('ACF')) {
    //  The ACF class doesn't exist, so you can probably redefine your functions here
}
```

I use exactly this in my own plugins that rely on the presence of ACF so that if it happens to get deactivated, the whole site doesn't bomb out.

Answer (score 2):

There is a wordpress function for that:

```php
is_plugin_active('advanced-custom-fields/acf.php');
```

Note: You might run into issues when changing to the premium version of a plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a good way to check if the plugin function exists.

You can also try [is_plugin_active](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) function to check if the plugin is activated, because the function can be redeclared somewhere.

I think the main reason you are doing that is to prevent Fatal Errors, so it doesn't matter which way you can use.

Comment: ACF can be shipped as a library within a theme framework or another plugin. `function_exists()` is a safer way to check.

Comment: Correct, but if it's a library within a theme framework or another plugin, it's expected that it will be activated by the theme or another plugin.

Comment: No, not necessary. If it's shipped as a library or composer package, it may be used as an actual library, loaded via simple include / autoloading. In this case, it won't be activated as a plugin or even listed in plugins at all. It will be loaded, but not as an active plugin, I use it this way with Composer all the time.